# homebrew php install on El Capitan fails @ nghttp2 dependency

Tags: laravel, macos, homebrew, valet

Following the Laravel guide to install valet on MacOS 10.11 El Capitan using homebrew, fails during php install @ nghttp2 dependency

Specifically php install depends on httpd which in turn depends on nghttp2.

nghttp2 installation fails with (Brew was unable to install [nghttp2].)

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/<username>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/nghttp2/02.make: _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT shrpx_client_handler.cc:1002:10: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'unique_ptr

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
```

Homebrew does warn that my OS is out of date and unsupported, however, El Capitan is the latest OS that will install on my hardware.

I have tried brew installing an older version of nghttp2, thinking that might compile on El Cap, but no luck.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

install before

```
brew install gcc
brew install --cc=gcc-8 nghttp2
```